# Loop with if/else using systematic variable header names

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I'm a new user to R and am having trouble understanding how I can loop an ifelse logic statement across a series of similarly named variables. I have sex and age attributes for the first 30 members of a household and would like to create a new variable for each member of the household that provides a value of 1 if the household member is both female and an adult (ie. over 18). I will eventually sum the values to calculate the number of adult females within the household.  I feel like this is not a hard problem but my pee-brain is stumped.  Thanks you in advance for any help, the unlooped workaround that I have come up with is shown below.

```
vulnerable$AF1 <- ifelse (vulnerable$relation_sex_1 == "female" & vulnerable$relation_age_1 >= 18, 1, 0)

vulnerable$AF2 <- ifelse (vulnerable$relation_sex_2 == "female" & vulnerable$relation_age_2 >= 18, 1, 0)

vulnerable$AF3 <- ifelse (vulnerable$relation_sex_3 == "female" & vulnerable$relation_age_3 >= 18, 1, 0)

vulnerable$AF4 <- ifelse (vulnerable$relation_sex_4 == "female" & vulnerable$relation_age_4 >= 18, 1, 0)

vulnerable$AF5 <- ifelse (vulnerable$relation_sex_5 == "female" & vulnerable$relation_age_5 >= 18, 1, 0)

vulnerable$AF6 <- ifelse (vulnerable$relation_sex_6 == "female" & vulnerable$relation_age_6 >= 18, 1, 0)
```

...

Comment: you should look into `dplyr::mutate_each` ; or turn your data.frame into long form with `tidyr::gather` which will gather all columns into one. It's hard to help more without any data to look at.

Comment: if you use the `vulnerable[, "relation_sex_1"]`  notation, you can use a variable which would let you use a vector of names in a loop, but if you showed more code/data there is definitely a better way for this.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide example data, so I'll create some first:

```
x = data.frame(sex = c("m", "f", "f", "f"), age=c(19,10,20,21))
> x
  sex age
1   m  19
2   f  10
3   f  20
4   f  21
```

If you just need to count your adult females quickly, use the `which`, together with `length`:

```
> which(x$sex == "f" & x$age >= 18) # points to matching indices
[1] 3 4
length(which(x$sex == "f" & x$age >= 18))
[1] 2
```

If you want to create a new variable, you could use a for-loop:

```
x$adultfemale = NA
for(i in 1:nrow(x)) { 
    if(x$sex[i] == "f" & x$age[i] >= 18) {
        x$adultfemale[i] = 1
    } else {
        x$adultfemale[i] = 0
    }
}
```

Or, better yet, the vectorized `ifelse`, which you already tried yourself, particularly if your dataset is large (this is quicker):

```
x$adultfemale2 = NA
x$adultfemale2 = ifelse(x$sex == "f" & x$age >= 18, 1, 0)
x
  sex age adultfemale adultfemale2
1   m  19           0            0
2   f  10           0            0
3   f  20           1            1
4   f  21           1            1
sum(x$adultfemale) # sum over the column
[1] 2
```